# Facing admin new shipment errors

Tags: magento2, shipment

> Since 3-4 days in admin when i am generating new shipments then
>   getting below errors

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Anyone know about above errors ?

Comment: Is there more info in your log files?

Comment: @ArnoVandeCappelle No there is no any information in log files